# Where should I upload telegram bot's files to run?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I'm just creating a telegram bot using Python and MySQL. It's currently only run on XAMPP. May I know how can I upload it to server so that everyone can use the bot although my computer is turned off ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

- To store code, You can use [Github](https://github.com) or
  [Gitlab](https://gitlab.com)
- For deploying (hosting on a server) you can use any cloud services like [Heroku](https://heroku.com), [Railway](https://railway.app), [Qovery](https://www.qovery.com) or [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/).